# Can functions and dysfunctions exist without teleology?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language

I feel as if something such as "the heart evolved to beat and pump blood" or "the function of the heart is to beat and pump blood" relies on the teleological belief that organs have a "right" way to be which again relies on the belief that there is a "purpose". Without teleology, and without the belief that there is a purpose, how can there be a right way to be and how can functions and dysfunctions make sense?

Comment: A function is a system that transforms inputs into outputs. It can be interpreted as having a purpose or not. That is, purpose depends on the interpretation, and not conversely, what you are asking.

Comment: The mathematical meaning of "function" is as @RodolfoAP says, but function has another meaning: "the purpose that something serves". This kind of function is, as you suggest, teleological. It's not that function requires teleology; it's that in this usage the word "function" has a teleological meaning.

Comment: The SEP article [on teleological terms/notions in biology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/teleology-biology/) is a good place to start glossing this subject. That said, teleological concepts occur on a spectrum: it is one thing to say, "X's function is A," another, "The purpose of X is to A," and yet another, "X's destiny is to A." Also, beware of reducing deontic concepts like "right" to merely something like "fulfills a purpose."

Comment: To an extent the word "heart" is in itself a description of function. A (good) heart *is* a thing that pumps blood.

Answer (score 5):

The remarkable thing about natural evolution is that it is a random, unguided process that can generate complex entities that behave *as if* designed for a purpose.

To see how this can happen, note that evolution requires three interdependent effects to occur:

1. *reproduction*, which creates copies of existing entities that *inherit* at least some traits of the original entity;
2. *mutation*, which causes those inherited traits in new entities to (sometimes) differ slightly from those of their originals; and
3. *selection*, which causes some of these inheritable traits to affect the survival and reproduction rate of the entities possessing them.

In general, both mutation and selection can be either "artificial", i.e. driven by an intelligent agent towards a specific purpose, or "natural", i.e. driven solely by unguided physical processes.

For example, humans have long bred dogs and other domestic animals for specific purposes by *selective breeding*, i.e. by choosing which animals are allowed to breed and pass on their traits, and with modern science we have also learned to manipulate the mutation part of the process via *genetic engineering*.  Yet, on the other hand, biological mutation and selection have both been happening for billions of years even before humans showed up, with no apparent evidence of conscious intelligent guidance.

It is, of course, quite possible and even common for organisms to influence the evolution of other organisms even *without* conscious intent or purpose.  For example, a lion that chases a herd of gazelles and picks out the slowest one to catch and eat will, through no intent of its own, end up creating a selection pressure that favors gazelles that can run fast.  And some micro-organisms such as retroviruses and [some parasitic bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolbachia) can even directly manipulate the genomes of their hosts even though, again, they do so with no "purpose" other than their own survival and reproduction.

The end result of these three effects, acting together over a sufficiently long time, is a set of entities that *appear* to have been designed and optimized for a particular way of life, with complex traits that serve to help them survive and reproduce: a gazelle has strong legs for running, a lion has sharp claws and teeth for catching its prey, a penguin has thick body fat and feathers to protect it against the cold and flippers to swim fast, a male peacock has a flashy tail to attract females, a virus has coat proteins to help it avoid the host's immune system (which itself is a very complex evolved trait!) and enter its cells.

But none of those traits have *actually* been designed, as far as we know, with any goal in mind — they just happen to assist the survival and reproduction of the organisms possessing them, and thus any individuals born, purely by chance, with more effective versions of those traits have been better able to pass their versions of those traits on to their offspring.

---

The other side of the coin is that, in practice, it's very hard to talk about biology and evolution without using language that *sounds* teleological.  The only alternative is to use awkward circumlocutions such as:

> "humans and their ancestors have evolved under conditions where having a heart that beats and pumps blood has, on average, increased their likelihood of survival and reproduction"

instead of:

> "the human heart has evolved to beat and pump blood"

or just:

> "humans have a heart to pump blood".

No natural human language (that I know of, at least) has convenient vocabulary and/or grammar for distinguishing between "designed for a purpose" and "*evolved* for a purpose" — or, if you want to be pedantic, "evolved under conditions where organisms with these particular traits or abilities have had an increased likelihood of survival and reproduction compared to those that don't, or that only have them to a lesser extent".

That said, language is also subject to evolution, and perhaps in time we will — whether intentionally or not — develop a clearer and more convenient terminological distinction between "purpose" and "evolutionary advantage".  Until then, however, biologists will continue to (mis)use teleological terms to describe evolution and its results, because the alternatives are quite unfit for any kind of practical communication.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

First, think of a [weeble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weeble). If you push the weeble off-balance, it will return to an equilibrium state. The balanced state is an *[attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor)* for the weeble. Schematically, a simple attractor looks like this:

[image]

You see a lot of arrows pointing towards the center. This means that if the system is pushed away from the center, the arrows push it back.

It doesn't require a human interpretation to decide whether something is an attractor or not. That's just math; which way do the arrows point? And it doesn't require any inherent notion of good or bad. It just means that you have a system that, when pushed away from a certain state, tends to go back towards that state.

If a system can be divided into parts, the function of a part *with respect to an attractor of the system* is the role that part plays in pushing the system towards the attractor.

Animals have an attractor state called "[homeostasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeostasis)." Homeostasis involves a certain body temperature, a certain concentration of water and different chemicals in each of the different tissues of the body, the maintained presence of certain physical structures, and so on. If the body falls out of homeostasis, many, many biological mechanisms act to push the body back towards homeostasis.

The function of one of those mechanisms (with respect to maintaining homeostasis) is nothing more or less than the causal role it plays in returning the body to homeostasis. For example, the function of the liver is to filter out certain chemicals (that we call toxins) from the blood, and introduce new chemicals to the blood. We do not have to say this is good or bad; we don't have to say homeostasis is "good" or lack of it is "bad."

We can simply say that the fact the liver filters and introduces those specific chemicals, increases the tendency of the body to return to an attractor state (homestasis), distinguished from other states only by the fact that so many arrows "point to it."

Comment: The fact that by taking some liberties you can describe a subset of functions in a non-teleological way does not mean that the notion itself is not teleological.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Homeostasis isn't the only attractor relevant in biology. At a population level, there's an attractor towards increased population size. If predators are introduced or food is reduced, many biological mechanisms come into play to maintain or increase the population anyway, if possible. Just like a weeble regaining its balance after being pushed. We can look at the function of traits of the organism *with respect to increasing population size*, which is the causal role they play those traits play in increasing the population size.

Comment: I don't know how to respond to that response other than by repeating my original comment.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Perhaps I misunderstood you then. I thought the emphasis in your prior comment was on the word "subset," and that by explaining the rest of the biological functions in the same way, your objection would be addressed.

Comment: But you haven't explained the rest of the biological function, not to mention all of the non-biological functions. The function of a cat's whiskers is to help it navigate in the dark. There is no single attractor that is served by navigating in the dark. It may be seeking food, it may be seeking a mate, it may be seeking to sneak up on another cat to pounce on it, or it may just be exploring. In order to explain this non-teleologically, you need to create an artificial attractor that logically reduces to "do the kinds of things cats do".

Comment: Furthermore, there are non-biological functions. In a trail sign with two rocks stack on top of each other and a third rock indicating the direction, the function of the third rock is to indicate direction. The function of a claw hammer is to drive nails, although it can be used in other contexts, where its function might be to add stress marks to a board (for an artificial aging affect) or to kill someone. There is no mechanical description of a hammer which includes all of the functions that it can serve.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Attractors aren't artificial; that's my point. They arise naturally because they are "where the arrows point." You can't arbitrarily name something an attractor, unless the arrows already point to it. The cat's whiskers can be understood, like everything else biological, in terms of how they help cause an increase in the population of the cat, or (even more generally) in terms of how they help cause an increase in the genes that code for the whiskers.

Comment: I didn't address claw hammers, as they are not biological, but claw hammers *can* be addressed by reference to human goal-seeking behavior. That is, the function of a claw hammer - *with respect to a human goal* - is how the claw hammer helps cause that goal to be achieved. A human goal is also an attractor; if a human is seeking a goal, and you put some obstacle in their way to move them away from the goal, the human will move back towards it, in the state space of variables relevant to the goal.

Comment: Chiral compounds are an example of an attractor without a goal - once life settled on mostly left-handed amino acids, that forced the chirality of a lot of other biologically generated compounds.  There was no goal-seeking.  It is just more efficient to have a single chirality, but it didn't matter whether it was right- or left-handed.  What we ended up with was largely the result of random chance initial "choice".

Comment: That was my point. The notion of attractor you are using is just a word for "whatever purpose is being served". There is no single theory. I give you a purpose; you say: "I hereby redefine that purpose as an attractor". But it's the same thing, just different wording. I say, "Cat's grow." You say, "A bunch of random events happen to conspire so that cats increase in size." You are just turning away from functionality, not explaining it.

Comment: @DavidGudeman The word "attractor" has a mathematical definition. If a set of points in the state space of a system is an attractor, it means that the system tends to approach that set of points over time, if the system is initially started in a state "near enough" to the attractor. We don't need the concept of "purpose" to define the concept of an "attractor."

Comment: OK, let me try again. I asked about the attractor associated with a cat's whiskers. You said population growth of cats or gene whiskers. But according to that definition any use of cats whiskers that does not lead to population growth of cats or genes means the whiskers are not functioning properly. That's clearly false. If a is using his whiskers to find his way to a a cat-killing dog, the whiskers are functioning properly. Now, you could try to get past this by some explanation for the potential of whiskers to lead to population growth of cats or genes,

Comment: but I can keep coming up with difficulties until you are pressed back to an explanation identical to the usual functional explanation, just using concepts such as potential to substitution for teleology. Almost every form of reductionism has this weakness: pressed to the limits, it ends up postulating things equivalent to the reduced things with no justification for the postulation except that is it needed for the reduction.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Well, if you already admit that an explanation identical to the usual functional explanation is *possible*, using physical and mathematical concepts such as potential to substitute for teleology, then I don't think we have any point of disagreement. In other words, you agree it is possible to explain purpose and function in terms of physical and mathematical concepts.

Comment: @DavidGudeman In the specific example of the cat using its whiskers to find a cat-killing dog, the problem is which system you're looking at: the individual cat, the population of cats, or the set of genes encoding cat whiskers? The function of whiskers I described in respect to the population of cats, isn't directly applied to any individual cat. There are other attractors that might be considered instead for the case of the individual cat, such as the cat's psychological goals.

Comment: Yes, I acknowledge that functionality is observationally equivalent to a set of possible physical events, namely those possible events that exhibit the functional behavior. What I deny is that it is possible to describe this set in advance without appealing to a teleological notion. In the cat whiskers case, you appeal to "other attractors". Which other attractors? Well, exactly those other attractors needed to describe the functional behavior. You can't come up with the set in advance; you need to anticipate all examples of functional behavior.

Comment: I often use the analogy of reducing the concept of a straight line to the concept of a set of points. Which sets of points? Well, those sets of points that lie on a straight line. Any attempt to define this set ultimately makes use of already knowing what a straight line is. A linear equation? Only in a coordinate system based on straight lines. The minimal distance between two points? Only in a space where the minimum distance is a straight line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135725/discussion-between-causative-and-david-gudeman).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, organs have a **function** in an organism. And when they no longer achieve this task then organs become dysfunctional.

In order to attribute a function to an organ one needs an **organism** to which the organ provides a service.

A given function has not been implemented necessarily on the basis of an anterior plan. The function can also be the result of an **adaptation** to the enviromental conditions according to the mechanism of natural evolution. It is a basic axiom of the theory of natural evolution that the concept of teleology does not apply.

Aside: From a philosophical point of view Aristotle's doctrine of the four causes has to be restricted: Not every thing and not even every function has a final cause (= telos).

Comment: Good answer, the Wikipedia article also clarifies the difference between extrinsic and intrinsic purposes. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology

Answer (score 1):

"how can there be a right way"

This is assuming that e.g. the heart is the *right* way to pump blood rather than just an acceptable way to pump blood.  Evolution doesn't necessarily create perfect solutions to problems, just adequate solutions for the survival of the trait.

Note that humans have legs despite the fact that wheels would be a more efficient means of locomotion.  Legs are however a pretty good compromise between the ease of production and efficiency.

As a further example, a lot of chemical compounds are [chiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(chemistry)) (can occur in two forms that are chemically identical but physically different via mirror symmetry).  However, nature quite often only uses either the right-handed or left-handed version of the compound, but not both ([homochirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homochirality)).  Neither is "right" - nature could have picked either chirality.  So we end up with compounds that either function in our bodies or they do not, and there is no real reason for it other than chance.

Comment: I don't think that for most of human history wheels would have been a more efficient means of locomotion. The efficiency of wheels depends a lot on even surfaces.

Comment: @towr I suspect wheels are more efficient on the savanna (an off-road bike is more efficient than walking or running), but my point is that there is no teleology, evolution only finds solutions that have an advantage over what it already there, which does not imply finding the "right" solution, just one that is "good enough for now".  The original question is based on an incorrect premise.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial evolution doesn't even find "good enough" solutions. It finds everything and literal survivorship bias finds which ones are good enough.

Comment: @user253751 "survivorship" is a fundamental component of evolution by natural selection, not a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of defining disease is still under heated debate in the context of mental health, so it is easier to start there and generalize to physical health. The [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mental-disorder/#FormDefi) gives 5 examples of formal definitions for mental illness, 3 of which avoid teleology. It is worth mentioning that they have different problems, so you have to be careful before accepting one.

> A disease is the absence of [statistically] normal function of a
> mechanism or process in a person that detracts from the person’s
> survival or reproduction.

According to this definition, the proper functioning of the heart whatever the heart does in the majority of the time in the majority of individuals. This definition avoids teleology, but has to justify why deviating from the average should be considered as sign of illness.

> A mental malady is a condition of a person, other than his rational
> beliefs and desires, such that he is suffering, or at increased risk
> of suffering, an evil (death, pain, disability, loss of freedom or
> opportunity, or loss of pleasure), in the absence of a distinct
> sustaining cause.

If you generalizing this definition to apply to physical disease, then a heart attack is considered a disease because it causes bad things to happen to people who have them. The proper function of an organ is essentially whatever function would bring about the best results. This view could probably work for physical diseases, it is overly broad regarding mental disease.

> A condition is pathological if and only if it is an [statistically]
> abnormal bodily/mental condition that requires medical intervention
> and that harms standard members of the species in standard conditions.

This definition defines dysfunction just like the first did, as a deviation from the statistical average, so it has the same big problems. The main difference is that it changes the focus from evolutionary fitness (i.e. survival and reproduction) to "standard" situations.

Answer (score 0):

These article seems to explain what you are asking about:

1. http://mechanism.ucsd.edu/teaching/w10/cummins.functions.1975.pdf
2. https://iep.utm.edu/func-exp/